# Accessing data in nests d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nested

I've been running into an issue that's been bothering me for a few days.

My data looks like this:

Origin  Area    Warehouse   WarehouseID
A   Jack    Alpha   1
B   Jack    Bravo   2
C   Jack    Delta   3
D   Charles Alpha   1
E   Charles Bravo   2
F   Charles Delta   3
G   Beau    Alpha   1
H   Beau    Bravo   2
I   Beau    Delta   3
J   Taco    Alpha   1
K   Taco    Bravo   2
L   Taco    Delta   3
M   Vigo    Alpha   1
N   Vigo    Bravo   2
O   Vigo    Delta   3

What I want to do is make a list of blocks on the left with the origins. Have a list of blocks in the middle with the warehouses. Then in the warehouses I'd place the different areas.

I've made the list of blocks on the left and the middle by using d3.map:

```
            var warehouse = d3.map(data, function(d){
            return d.Warehouse;
            })
            .keys();

            svg.selectAll("DWH")
                .data(DWHs)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", w/2)
                .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                        return (i * (h / warehouse.length))+ 5;
                })
                .attr("width", 200)
                .attr("height", (h / (warehouse.length + 0.5)));
```

Which worked nicely. However when I want to add the areas within the Warehouse blocks I need to be able to refer to which warehouse the block should be in. Which I think isn't possible with the map function, but should be possible with d3.nest. So I've tried something like this:

```
            var wrangled = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d){
                return d.WarehouseID;
                })
            .entries(data);
```

But then I have to access the data when I want to draw the warehouses.. So I thought something along the lines of this:

```
            svg.selectAll("DWH")
            .data(wrangled)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", w/2)
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                    return (i * (h / key.length))+ 5;
            })
            .attr("width", 200)
            .attr("height", (h / (warehouse.length + 0.5)));
```

But key.length is not really a thing, and I haven't been able to find a way to access the size of nest.

So I've just been going with the previous code, but then when I want to draw the areas within the warehouses I run into another problem. I need to able to say that for instance, in the first line of the data: the area Jack, has to be drawn within warehouse Alpha. Which should be doable with an if statement and a nest. But I have no idea where to start. I've been trying to understand nests, and found quite some resources on it, but not on how to access the different parts of the nest when you want to draw something using one. Can someone help me with this?

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For nested data, use a `forEach` loop and access data elements using `d.key` and `value`.